# About $\int(2x^6-2x^4+3)\cos^{-1}(ax)dx$

Tags: calculus, contest-math

> For $a>0$, let
> $$
> I(a)= \displaystyle\int\limits_{\frac{-1}{a}}^{\frac{1}{a}}(2x^6-2x^4+3)\cos^{-1}(ax)\mathrm dx.
> $$
> Then:
>
> 1. $I(a)<\dfrac{129\pi}{35a}$.
> 2. $I(a)$ is independent of $a$.
> 3. $I(a)=\left(\dfrac{2}{7a^7}+\dfrac{2}{5a^5}+\dfrac{3}{a}\right)$.
> 4. $I(1)=0$
> 5. None of these

I tried by taking $\cos^{-1}(ax)$ at it's maximum value I.e $\pi$ and solving , but that sounds wrong.And neither it gives correct answer.
Also I referred [this answer](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2112644p15304154), but it's too vague and I don't get what they mean by IBB.

I would appreciate some approaches, ideas to this question.

Comment: IBB is a typo. It should be IBP, which stands for integration by parts

Answer (score 3):

The indefinite integration is not required here. From the property of definite integrals, we have:
$$I=\int_{-b}^b f(x)\ dx=\int_{0}^b (f(x)+f(-x))\ dx$$
Also, $\cos^{-1} (-x)=\pi-\cos^{-1} x$.
Using these, we have:
$$I(a)=\pi \int_{0}^{\frac 1a} (2x^6-2x^4+3)\ dx$$
This is easily evaluable.

Comment: Thanks,  so I get $I(a)= \pi (\frac{2}{7a^7} - \frac{2}{5a^5} +\frac{3}{a}$) how can we calculate it's maximum value? By differentiation right , I.e where I'(a)=0.

Comment: And it has scary roots.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the first option is incorrect. Plot it on Desmos, it isn't valid.

Comment: Then, what will be maximum value of I(a) ?